# Upload a video to YouTube or Facebook from your app? (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, facebook, video, upload, gdata

I'm trying to find a way to upload a video to Facebook. I know It is possible as some apps do it. I was searching the web for hours but no results. I know it's somehow related to GData. 
I managed to upload a video to youtube, can I somehow convert the code so it will upload to Facebook?

Answer (score 2):

To a upload a video on Facebook, try [this](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/532/). They have a sample code here on how to upload a video using the Facebook Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that the best way is to upload a video to youtube by using GData, and then post only link for it to Facebook by using FBConnect Objective-C library.